# UITextView starting from bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, xcode-storyboard

I'm having trouble with a **UITextView**. I have seen other people have had this issue before, but whenever my app loads on my phone, all the **UITextViews** start from the bottom of their text and I have to scroll up.

I have tried numerous solutions but I need a solution to use on ONLY the Storyboard as I have some views without designated classes.

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

I think this is happening when scrolling is enabled - so how do I have scrolling enabled but stop this from happening?

Comment: I wasn't able to recreate your problem, could you take some screenshots of what you have selected in your xcode attributes inspector @Prateek

Comment: Images added for one of the textviews. I even tried unticking 'Adjust scroll view insets' on the main view controller but that didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Can not reproduce your issue on iOS 9.2,but you may try this

Set `contentOffset` with Runtime Attribtues

[image]

Comment: No luck with this either :/

Answer (score 2):

I face same problem and I still cannot find a solution using `Storyboard` only.
However, using the code below can prevent your `TextView` auto start at bottom

If your `TextView` is in `UIViewController`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.myTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
}
```

If your `TextView` is in `UIView`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [self.myTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: thanks a lot buddy, am really upset from this issue. Finally you help me out from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

`[self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];`

Comment: Ok, but is there an any reason for that??

Comment: I have specified the reason in my question - I don't have class files associated with some views and so I am not wanting to create new files just to accommodate this fix if there is a simple way through storyboard