# UITextView starts at bottom iOS10

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, ios10

There's been a known issue before with UITextViews starting at the bottom of the view and then having to scroll up.

I managed to fix this previously using the following

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self.desc setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```

However since updating to iOS 10, this doesn't solve the problem. Has anyone got any updated fixes?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're talking about. Do you have a link to that *known issue*? Or can you add a screenshot and some more relevant code?

Comment: This is the previous issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452005/uitextview-starting-from-bottom?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, Its what I used to use for this kind of issue, I hope this works.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    // To make the textView scroll to begining of the text view
    [self.myTextView scrollRectToVisible:[self.myTextView caretRectForPosition:self.myTextView.beginningOfDocument] animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago and I really didn't find useful answering for it. As a result I created a `UIScrollView` with UILabel in it - i got a necessary behaviour. Possible this way also suitable for you.

Hope it helps you!